# Accessing Knockout JS ViewModel Function Externally

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a KnockoutJS view model which has a function I need to access. The ViewModel is populated initially and `ko.applyBindings` called.  This all works fine.

The problem is when trying to call the `viewModel.RefreshData()` function from outside of the the ViewModel (i.e. from other JavaScript code).

Mozilla is reporting `TypeError: viewModel.RefreshData` is not a function. I think the problem may be related to the Knockout Mapping plugin 'overwriting' the function.

The code is as follows:

```
var EditorViewModel = function (data) {

    var _self = this;

    _self.Data = ko.observable('');        

    _self.LoadData = function () {
        _self.Data(new ChildViewModel(data));
    };

    _self.RefreshData = function (_data) {
        _self.Data(new ChildViewModel(_data));
    };

    _self.LoadData(data);

    return _self;

};

var ChildViewModel = function (data) {

    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);        
};


// On first load with modelData from AJAX:
var viewModel = new EditorViewModel(modelData);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// When refreshing with newModelData from AJAX call:
viewModel.RefreshData(newModelData); // ERROR IS THROWN HERE!
```

Note that a ChildViewModel is used in order that the data/view can be refreshed.

Comment: The description of the error does not seem to match the code you provided: in the error message, you try to call `RefreshData` on the constructor `EditorViewModel` instead of on the instantiated object `viewModel`.

Comment: @janfoeh I've edited the question to correct this

Comment: I tested with the code you provided and it's working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nd80jfr7/1/

Comment: @Graham you left out the actual AJAX call. I suspect that this is where your problem lies - `viewModel` is somehow out of scope there.

Comment: @Graham I've added a few comments about issues I see in your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/dwztmquk/), and have added a suggestion for an improved version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/dwztmquk/1/).